# Use dynamically created react components and fill with state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

Below is a proof of concept pen. I'm trying to show a **lot** of input fields and try to collect their inputs when they change in one big object. As you can see, the input's won't change their value, which is what I expect, since they're created once with the `useEffect()` and filled that in that instance.

I think that the only way to solve this is to use **`React.cloneElement`** when `values` change and inject the new value into a cloned element. This is why I created 2000 elements in this pen, it would be a major performance hog because every element is rerendered when the state changes. I tried to use `React.memo` to only make the inputs with the changed value rerender, but I think `cloneElement` simply rerenders it anyways, which sounds like it should since it's cloned.

How can I achieve a performant update for a single field in this setup?

https://codepen.io/10uur/pen/LYPrZdg

**Edit**: a working pen with the `cloneElement` solution that I mentioned before, the noticeable performance problems and that all inputs rerender.

https://codepen.io/10uur/pen/OJLEJqM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve the desired behavior : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-glade-73ivx

Some tips :

1. I would not recommend putting React elements in the state, prefer putting plain data (array, objects, ...) in the state that will be mapped to React elements in the return/render method.
2. Don't forget to use a `key` prop when rendering an array of elements
3. Use `React.memo` to avoid re-rendering components when the props are the same
4. Use `React.useCallback` to memoize callback (this will help when using `React.memo` on children)
5. Use the functional form of the state setter to access the old state and update it (this also helps when using `React.useCallback` and avoid recreating the callback when the state change)

Here is the complete code :

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const INPUTS_COUNT = 2000;

const getInitialState = () => {
  const state = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < INPUTS_COUNT; i++) {
    // Only put plain data in the state
    state.push({
      value: Math.random(),
      id: "valueContainer" + i
    });
  }

  return state;
};

const Root = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState(getInitialState());
  }, []);

  // Use React.useCallback to memoize the onChangeValue callback, notice the empty array as second parameter
  const onChangeValue = React.useCallback((id, value) => {
    // Use the functional form of the state setter, to update the old state
    // if we don't use the functional form, we will be forced to put [state] in the second parameter of React.useCallback
    // in that case React.useCallback will not be very useful, because it will recreate the callback whenever the state changes
    setState(state => {
      return state.map(item => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return { ...item, value };
        }
        return item;
      });
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {state.map(({ id, value }) => {
        // Use a key for performance boost
        return (
          <ValueContainer
            id={id}
            key={id}
            onChangeValue={onChangeValue}
            value={value}
          />
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

// Use React.memo to avoid re-rendering the component when the props are the same
const ValueContainer = React.memo(({ id, onChangeValue, value }) => {
  const onChange = e => {
    onChangeValue(id, e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <br />
      Rerendered: {Math.random()}
      <br />
      <input type="text" value={value} onChange={onChange} />
      <br />
    </>
  );
});

ReactDOM.render(<Root />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thanks! This has a lot of useful stuff in there and actually fixes the problems in the codepen.